# Are legal and licensing issues welcome here?

Tags: discussion, support, scope

Are legal and licensing questions allowed on AskUbuntu? Such as questions asking about legality of using the logo elsewhere, etc? Or questions asking about licensing? Which are questions about Ubuntu, but not really its use, and more about how it can be used, and how it and its associated parts (such as logo) can be legally distributed and used.

Comment: As long as it's about Ubuntu, I don't see why not. Besides, there's even a [tag:legal] tag.

Comment: They might be better off (in terms having people who know licensing) at [opensource.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it is clear, maybe - but most of the time the trap that questions fall into is seeking legal advice that we can't give.

Most of the time the only answer without possibly giving them harmful or misleading advice is "Ask Canonical" - http://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/contact-us - that address specifically for how Ubuntu and it's logo can be used.

---

Examples (against):

https://askubuntu.com/q/666635/47291

[Can I use the Ubuntu logo on t-shirts produced non-comercially?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164616/can-i-use-the-ubuntu-logo-on-t-shirts-produced-non-comercially) (quoted text has changed, many say things like "It's Fine!" - when it may not really be...)

[Am I allowed to display the ubuntu logo?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361889/am-i-allowed-to-display-the-ubuntu-logo?rq=1)

[Is it possible to create Ubuntu Shirts ( Merchandise )](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106735/is-it-possible-to-create-ubuntu-shirts-merchandise)

[Can the Ubuntu logo be used for my business?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592514/can-the-ubuntu-logo-be-used-for-my-business?rq=1)

[Is it legal to use Ubuntu name for my cybercafé?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592442/is-it-legal-to-use-ubuntu-name-for-my-cybercaf%C3%A9?lq=1) - three link answers saying "ask"

Examples (for):

[Can the Ubuntu logo be used for a commercial website?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58428/can-the-ubuntu-logo-be-used-for-a-commercial-website) - answer is clear